# fillna by referring another column but copy same column value using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, fillna

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'sub_code' : [np.nan, 'CSE01', np.nan, 
                   'CSE02', 'CSE03', 'CSE02',
                   'CSE03', 'CSE02'],
     'stud_level' : [101, 101, 101, 101, 
                  101, 101, 101, 101],
     'grade' : ['STA','STA','PSA','STA','STA','SSA','PSA','QSA']})
```

I would like to do the below

a) Fill NA's in `sub_code` column by referring `grade` column.

b) For ex: grade `STA` has corresponding `sub_code` non-NA values in `row 1,3 and 4` (`row 0 has NA value`)

c) Copy the very 1st non-NA (`CSE01`) value from `grade` column and put it in `sub_code` column (`row 0`)

I tried the below

```
m = df['sub_code'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'sub_code'] = np.where(df.loc[m, 'grade'].ne(np.nan), df['sub_code'], 'not filled')
```

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['sub_code'] =df.groupby(['grade'])['sub_code'].bfill().ffill()



   sub_code  stud_level grade
0    CSE01         101   STA
1    CSE01         101   STA
2    CSE03         101   PSA
3    CSE02         101   STA
4    CSE03         101   STA
5    CSE02         101   SSA
6    CSE03         101   PSA
7    CSE02         101   QSA
```

Comment: btw, I don't see any check for `NA` in your code. how does it fill exactly in `NA` rows

Comment: this would fail if NaN is not at the top, no?

Comment: yes, that was the same question I had as well.

Comment: Easypeasy, `.bfill().ffill()`

Comment: but that would no longer use the first non-NA, right?

Comment: Try it @enke and tells us where it fails, we shall remedy it with the same method

Comment: For `df = pd.DataFrame({'sub_code' : [np.nan, 'CSE01',  'CSE02', np.nan], 'grade' : ['STA','STA','STA','STA']})`, IIUC, the correct outcome is `['CSE01', 'CSE01', 'CSE02', 'CSE01']` but `bfill.ffill` won't produce that

Comment: What about `df['sub_code'].fillna(df.groupby(['grade'])['sub_code'].nth(1)[0])` so that we dont scan an elephant to get a rat

Comment: @enke, word of advice, use map, lambda etc as a last resort. Code readability is important. Dont vectorize the already vectorised

Comment: that works for this case, but since `nth` is murky on NaN values, I dunno if it's scalable, but I guess it's good enough for OP so it's good enough

Answer (score 1):

`groupby` "grade" and use `first` to get the first non-NaN sub_code in each grade. Then use `np.where` to fill NaN values in "sub_code":

```
mapper = df.groupby('grade')['sub_code'].first()
df['sub_code'] = np.where(df['sub_code'].isna(), df['grade'].map(mapper), df['sub_code'])
```

or instead of the second line, you can also use `fillna`:

```
df['sub_code'] = df.set_index('grade')['sub_code'].fillna(mapper)
```

Output:

```
  sub_code  stud_level grade
0    CSE01         101   STA
1    CSE01         101   STA
2    CSE03         101   PSA
3    CSE02         101   STA
4    CSE03         101   STA
5    CSE02         101   SSA
6    CSE03         101   PSA
7    CSE02         101   QSA
```

Comment: Hi @enke, If we are to use `multiple columns` to map, how do we do this? Let's say that I wish to map here based on two columns, `df[grade'].map(mapper)`

Comment: If I use two columns, it becomes a dataframe and `map` doesn't work on dataframe.

Comment: @TheGreat maybe you can stack the columns, map and then unstack back.