# Any method of Replacing NaN values with already existing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, fillna

I am working on a dataset in a Jupyter notebook. My dataset has two columns, 'State' and 'City' as you can see in image

[image]

Now, State has some missing values in it, So I want to fill NaN data based on the already existing data in the dataset.

[image: Missing values]

**For example**, in Image 2, the city is Chennai and the state is missing, So I want to fill Tamil Nadu in state column based on Image 1.

**Example 2** - I want to fill in the state of Andhra Pradesh, where city is Vishakapatnam and so on for all the NaN data .

Comment: Do you have one Pandas DF where some `state` values are missing but available for the same `city` at other rows in the DF. Or do you have 2 DFs, one with missing `state`  values which you want to fill in using the value for the same `city` in the other DF. Or what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fillna by referring another column but copy same column value using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70810829/fillna-by-referring-another-column-but-copy-same-column-value-using-pandas)

Comment: @user19077881 I have one Pandas DF where some state values are missing but available for the same city at other rows in the DF.

Comment: The please see my answer below. That was an essential clarification.

Answer (score 1):

As you have now commented "I have one Pandas DF where some state values are missing but available for the same city at other rows in the DF" then you can use `groupby` on the City and pick-up the state from other row entries for the same City. You can use the code below. The ffill and bfill replaces any NaN values before or after the correct State value.

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    'city': ['Delhi', 'Mumbai', 'Bangalore', 'Hyderabad', 'Chennai', 'Delhi', 'Chennai'],
    'state': ['Delhi', 'Maharashtra', 'Karnataka', 'Telangana', None, None, 'Tamil Nadu'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['state'] = df.groupby(['city'])['state'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())


print(df)
```

gives:

```
        city        state
0      Delhi        Delhi
1     Mumbai  Maharashtra
2  Bangalore    Karnataka
3  Hyderabad    Telangana
4    Chennai   Tamil Nadu
5      Delhi        Delhi
6    Chennai   Tamil Nadu
```

Comment: @user19077881 this is making evry state field as NaN. Please see my comment below

Comment: Answer code now edited to include sample data. The code gives the correct answer as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a dictionary that maps each city with its state then it will be a piece of cake.
for India, [this link](https://gist.github.com/anubhavshrimal/4aeb195a743d0cdd1c3806c9c222ed45) has a JSON file format for all cities and states in India.
Here is a sample code:

```
data = {
    'city': ['Delhi', 'Mumbai', 'Bangalore', 'Hyderabad', 'Chennai'],
    'state': ['Delhi', 'Maharashtra', 'Karnataka', 'Telangana', 'Tamil Nadu'],
}

city_state_dict = {
    'Delhi': 'Delhi',
    'Mumbai': 'Maharashtra',
    'Bangalore': 'Karnataka',
    'Hyderabad': 'Telangana',
    'Chennai': 'Tamil Nadu',
    'Kolkata': 'West Bengal',
    'Pune': 'Maharashtra',
}

# This line is to simulate the Nan valu in state column
added_row = pd.Series(['Kolkata', np.nan], index=['city', 'state']).to_frame().T
added_row_2 = pd.Series(['Kolkata', 'West Bengal'], index=['city', 'state']).to_frame().T
added_row_3 = pd.Series(['Pune', np.nan], index=['city', 'state']).to_frame().T
final = (
    pd.concat(
        [
            pd.DataFrame(data),
               added_row, added_row_2, added_row_3],
               axis=0,
               ignore_index=True)
    .assign(state=lambda df: df.city.map(city_state_dict))
)
final.head(10)
```

[image]

If you want a quick fix that doesn't cover all cases, you can use forward-fill and back-fill, for instance:

```
final = (
    pd.concat(
        [
            pd.DataFrame(tt),
               added_row,
               added_row_2,
               added_row_3],
               axis=0,
               ignore_index=True)
    # .assign(state=lambda df: df.city.map(city_state_dict))
    .assign(state= lambda df_: df_.groupby('city', group_key=False).state.apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill()))
)
final.head(10)
```

This will give this output, if there is one city that doesn't have a corresponding state in your data frame but you want to fill it, it will be a NaN with the `bfill()` and `ffill()`:
[image]

Why this happens? because we grouped by ***city*** and the city Pune has only one row in the group with no back or forward knowledge about the state to impute it.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

plz provide code not image and provide desired output

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'city': ['Delhi', 'Calcutta', 'Delhi', 'Chennai', 'Bokaro', 'Visakhapatnam', 'Chennai', 'Wanparti', 'Delhi', 'Mumbai'], 
         'state': ['Delhi', 'West Bengal', 'Delhi', 'TamilNadu', 'Jharkhand', 'AndhraPradesh', 'TamilNadu', 'AndhraPradesh', 'Delhi', 'Maharashtra']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'city': ['Pune', 'Visakhapatnam', 'Indore', 'Visakhapatnam', 'Chennai', 'Chennai', 'Indore', 'Chennai', 'Delhi', 'Pune']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2['state'] = np.nan
```

df1

```
    city            state
0   Delhi           Delhi
1   Calcutta        West Bengal
2   Delhi           Delhi
3   Chennai         TamilNadu
4   Bokaro          Jharkhand
5   Visakhapatnam   AndhraPradesh
6   Chennai         TamilNadu
7   Wanparti        AndhraPradesh
8   Delhi           Delhi
9   Mumbai          Maharashtra
```

df2

```
    city            state
0   Pune            NaN
1   Visakhapatnam   NaN
2   Indore          NaN
3   Visakhapatnam   NaN
4   Chennai         NaN
5   Chennai         NaN
6   Indore          NaN
7   Chennai         NaN
8   Delhi           NaN
9   Pune            NaN
```

**Code**

```
m = dict(df1.values)
df2.assign(state=df2['state'].fillna(df2['city'].map(m)))
```

output:

```
    city            state
0   Pune            NaN
1   Visakhapatnam   AndhraPradesh
2   Indore          NaN
3   Visakhapatnam   AndhraPradesh
4   Chennai         TamilNadu
5   Chennai         TamilNadu
6   Indore          NaN
7   Chennai         TamilNadu
8   Delhi           Delhi
9   Pune            NaN
```

Comment: I shared images of single dataframe, not 2 dataframes. So basically I have in one dataframe, Some values of state is missing, so i want to map with those which are already entered.